# Deleting data from one table using data from a second table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table table1, where there is a million data and a completely identical table table2, only there are only 106 data. How it is possible to delete these 106 data from table1?
In these two tables i have fields like id, date, param0, param1, param2.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that uniqueness is enforced through the `ID` column in both tables, then:

```
delete from table1 a
where exists (select null
              from table2 b
              where b.id = a.id
            );
```

Otherwise, add some more columns (into the `where` clause) which will help you delete only rows you really want.

Comment: For some reason, it deletes 107 data, and not 106 necessary

Comment: Then read the last sentence I wrote.